# Issue in accessing R. resources in Android 2.2

Tags: java, android, eclipse, resources

I am very new to Android application development. 
I successfully added some backgrounds to several layouts. And added media files to play. However when I rename a file in the folder structure, it shows an error that the resource does not exist. 
But I can see those files in `gen-><mypackage>->R.java->drawable`.

Now my background pictures and resources do not appear in code.
`R.layout.splashforproduct1` it shows an error for `splashforproduct1`.

not only `splashforproduct1` but this issue is the same for `R.raw.media.mp4`
This is not first time I have got this issues. Please help me.

I am using Android 2.2 with eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cleaning your project doesn't work try this: Scroll up to the top of the file and delete the import lines. Then wait for Eclipse to detect your changes and let it work out what you need to import and accept its suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just need to clean your project.
In Eclipse you do it clicking:
Project -> Clean    and then you choose your android project.

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work. When Ive added a new resource I always do that.

Comment: Did you try refreshing the project? Right click over the projecg folder in Eclipse and the Refresh

Comment: What's the name of the file? Does it contains any "strange" char like ?, :, ! or stuff like this?